# Need making super simple HTML/Javscript comment section for a small food shopping website for windows 10 laptop thanks please thank you very much

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I need help making a comment section for my webpage.
I've tried document.createElement and .appendChild() but it's not working out for me. I have attached what I have now.

```js
function leaveComment(){
  let name = String(document.getElementById('name').value);
  let topic = String(document.getElementById('topic').value);
  let comment = String(document.getElementById('commenttt').value);
  let userbox = document.createElement("div")
  userbox.className = "userbox"
  let pfp = document.createElement("div")
  pfp.className = "pfp"
  let commentation = document.createElement("div")
  commentation.className = "comment"
  let image = document.createElement("img")
  image.setAttribute('src', 'multimedia/images/pfp.jpg');
  image.setAttribute('alt', 'pic');
  let username = document.createElement("h2")
  let heading = document.createElement("h3")
  let text = document.createElement("p")
  const newName = document.createTextNode(name);
  const newTopic = document.createTextNode(topic);
  const newCom = document.createTextNode(comment);
  pfp.appendChild(image)
  pfp.appendChild(newName)
  comment.appendChild(newTopic)
  comment.appendChild(text)
  userbox.appendChild(pfp)
  userbox.appendChild(commentation)
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("comments")
  element.appendChild(userbox);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that code could use some more whitespace for readability. Try grouping related lines and separating the groups with an empty line.

You need to actually reference the right elements and actually fill the elements once you have created them. I think this does what you want:

```js
function leaveComment(){
  let name = String(document.getElementById('name').value);
  let topic = String(document.getElementById('topic').value);
  let comment = String(document.getElementById('commenttt').value);
  let userbox = document.createElement("div")
  userbox.className = "userbox"
  let pfp = document.createElement("div")
  pfp.className = "pfp"
  let commentation = document.createElement("div")
  commentation.className = "comment"
  let image = document.createElement("img")
  image.setAttribute('src', 'multimedia/images/pfp.jpg');
  image.setAttribute('alt', 'pic');
  let username = document.createElement("h2")
  let heading = document.createElement("h3")
  let text = document.createElement("p")
  text.appendChild(document.createTextNode(comment))
  username.innerHTML = name;
  heading.innerHTML = topic;
  const newCom = document.createTextNode(comment);
  pfp.appendChild(image)
  pfp.appendChild(username)
  commentation.appendChild(heading)
  commentation.appendChild(text)
  userbox.appendChild(pfp)
  userbox.appendChild(commentation)
  var element = document.getElementById("comment-section")
  element.appendChild(userbox);

}
```

```css
.pred {
width: 40%;
float: left;
}
.comments {
width: 50%;
float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="googleapis" content="noindex"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=KoHo:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>test</title>
  </head>



  <body>
    
  <div class="pred">
    <h1>Leave your comment!</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form class="" onsubmit="leaveComment()"  method="post">
      <p>Nickname or Name</p> <input id="name" required="required" type="text" name="" value="">
      <br>
      <p>Discussion Topic(s)-</p><input id="topic" required="required" type="text" name="" value="">
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>Comments: </p><textarea id="commenttt" required="required" name="name" rows="8" cols="20"></textarea>
      <button type="button" onclick="leaveComment()" name="button">Comment!</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="comments" id="comment-section">
    <h1>Comments</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="userbox">
      <div class="pfp">
        <img src="multimedia/images/pfp.jpg" alt="p">
        <h2>Bob</h2>

      </div>
      <div class="comment">
        <h3>Random Topic Haha</h3>
        <p>Random topic sucks</p>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>











  </body>

</html>
```

Sidenote:

I strongly suggest looking into webcomponents, E.g. LitElement

Makes everything much more organized.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in here

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("comments")
element.appendChild(userbox);
```

`getElementsByClassName` returns something called `HTMLCollection` which does not have `appendChild` method.

For the above code to work you need to call it like this

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("comments")
element[0].appendChild(userbox);
```